# XPath: get child value based on parent attribute

Tags: php, xml, xpath

Assuming an XML with the following structure:

```
<A>
  <B>
    <C>
      <D name='title1'>
        <E>
          <F data='d1'>ON</F>
        </E>
      </D>
      <D name='title2'>
        <E>
          <F data='d12'>ON</F>
        </E>
      </D>
    </C>
  </B>
</A>
```

How do I get "F" node output based on the "D" node attribute?
Sort of like this:

```
/A/B/C/D[@name='title1']/E/F
```

I can get the F node out using the following based on its attribute:

```
$status = $lol->xpath("//n:F[@data='d1']");
echo "Status: " . $status[0] . "</br>";
```

I tired to put variations of the xpath to get  what I want, but with no luck.

Ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
//D[@name='title1']//F
```

will give you `<F data='d1'>ON</F>`

```
//D[@name='title2']//F
```

should give you `<F data='d12'>ON</F>`

Answer (score 1):

Did you mean "Find all F based on parent D attribute?"

Here is example of "Find all F nodes that have D-parent-node with 'title' attribute equals to 'title1':

```
$xml = <<<XML
<A>
  <B>
    <C>
      <D name='title1'>
        <E>
          <F data='d1'>ON</F>
        </E>
      </D>
      <D name='title1'>
        <E>
          <F data='d12'>ON</F>
        </E>
      </D>
    </C>
  </B>
</A>
XML;

$oXml = new SimpleXmlElement($xml);

var_dump($oXml->xpath("//D[@name='title1']//F"));
```

I hope this would helpful for you.

Answer (score 0):

A nice simple  way I like to deal with kind of XML document, similar to your attempted `$status[0]`, is like this:

[working example](https://eval.in/96085)

```
$status = $xml->xpath("//D");

echo $status[0]['name'] . " is " . $status[0]->E->F .  "\r\n";
echo $status[1]['name'] . " is " . $status[1]->E->F . "\r\n";
```

Outputs:

```
title1 is ON
title2 is ON
```